# How to style Twitter Bootstrap's typeahead (e.g. set background color)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootstrap-sass

How can I set a custom background color for e.g., the active item in the dropdown when using Bootstrap's "typeahead" autocomplete?

A minor problem, but one that has been frustrating me for a couple of hours!

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap in a Rails 3.2 app, via the bootstrap-sass gem.

I assumed this was controlled by the dropdown menu styling, but

```
$dropdownLinkBackgroundHover: $customColor;
```

does not work.

I also tried a more specific approach

```
.typeahead .active > a, .typeahead .active > a:hover { background-color: $customColor; }
```

but this also does not appear to work.

What am I overlooking? Or should my fixes be working, and the issue lies elsewhere?

Comment: i think writing your custom css `.typeahead .active > a, .typeahead .active > a:hover { background-color: $customColor; }`  would work .But only when you write this after `@import bootstrap`, and not before it. In SASS, order of importing files and writing CSS matters.

Comment: thanks @RamandeepSingh, yes this is after `@import...` and among other css clases that are working. hmmm, ok useful to know that this should work, must be something else going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, it would appear that the `:hover` state is not used for the typeahead, but only the `.active` one, as seen in the [javascript plugin (2.2.2 on github)](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js#L270)

So if you change the color variable it has to be the `$dropdownLinkColorActive` variable (that will override all the dropdowns, whether there are from typeahead or not).

---

Secondly the little trick is that the background is not only set by the `background-color`, which is a fallback, but by the `background-image` as seen from the [Less call](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/less/dropdowns.less#L103) to the [Less mixin](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/less/mixins.less#L422) - code shown at the bottom.

And if you want to set a new color only to the dropdowns of typeahead, you have to override the color with the **`.typeahead +`**`.dropdown-menu .active > a` selector (at least for now).

[Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/KHSss/1/)

Here is what you have to override :

```css
.typeahead + .dropdown-menu .active > a,
.typeahead + .dropdown-menu .active > a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #FF77FF;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FF77FF, #FF44FF);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#FF77FF), to(#FF44FF));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF77FF, #FF44FF);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FF77FF, #FF44FF);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FF77FF, #FF44FF);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF77FF', endColorstr='#FF44FF', GradientType=0);
}
```

---

This is based on the original less version of Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2, but it most surely is the same for the sass ported version.

For posterity, here is the less code referenced (version 2.2.2) :

```css
/* called in .dropdown-menu .active > a */
#gradient > .vertical(@dropdownLinkBackgroundActive, darken(@dropdownLinkBackgroundActive, 5%));

/* mixin */
#gradient {
  .vertical(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333) {
    background-color: mix(@startColor, @endColor, 60%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), to(@endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",argb(@startColor),argb(@endColor))); // IE9 and down
  }
}
```

Comment: Very good answer! `$dropdownLinkBackgroundActive` was what I was after. But the extra detail is worth at least 3 up votes (unfortunately I can only award one).